# Best practice authentication for mobile

Tags: mobile, digest-authentication

I have developed a web site that requires user registration and authentication for some sections. Now I'm looking for a best practice to implement registration and authentication from a mobile app connecting to the server. This app will communicate using json with the server. I was thinking about HTTP digest, but I'd like to hear some one else opinion.

Just for the records, server is written in Grails (groovy) and uses spring security for authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you should post "j_username" and "j_password" to "/j_spring_security_check?ajax=true".

The spring-security plugin installs a LoginController, check it out to see the default exposed actions for ajax-based login.

For more in-depth information about the flow and code examples: [grails-spring-security-core](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#9.4%20Ajax%20Authentication)

Comment: I know about spring security, my concerns are about security and CSRF attacks. Posting to j_spring_security_check means clear text passwords and no CSRF token (because I can't generate it on a client application.

Comment: Of course, the url that receives a plain text password as well as any basic auth protected resources should be under https. About the CSRF, SS supports multi-factor authentication so maybe you could use a two-step auth process.